# are posix pipes lightweight?

Tags: c, linux, posix, pipe

In a linux application I'm using pipes to pass information between threads.

The idea behind using pipes is that I can wait for multiple pipes at once using poll(2). That works well in practice, and my threads are sleeping most of the time. They only wake up if there is something to do.

In user-space the pipes look just like two file-handles. Now I wonder how much resources such a pipes use on the OS side.

Btw: In my application I only send single bytes every now and then. Think about my pipes as simple message queues that allow me to wake-up receiving threads, tell them to send some status-data or to terminate.

Comment: Posix specifies the pipe interface, not the implementation, which is where the "weight" comes from.

Comment: How many channels? How many messages per second? Hundreds? Millions? Make a simple prototype using several technologies (anything from IPC message queues to pipes to UNIX sockets etc.) and compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using Linux you can investigate and compare `pipe` performance with `eventfd`'s.  They are technically faster and lighter weight but you'll be very lucky to actually see the gains in practice.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html

Comment: WOW! Thanks for pointing this out. I'm using pipes for this kind of things, and I'm sure I can replace at least half of them using eventfd's. Most of the time all I really want is to signal a state to a thread that is blocked in poll. If eventfd is more lightweight I'll use it.

Answer (score 8):

No, I would not consider pipes "lightweight", but that doesn't necessarily mean they're the wrong answer for your application either.

Sending a byte over a pipe is going to require a minimum of 3 system calls (write,poll,read). Using an in-memory queue and pthread operations (mutex_lock, cond_signal) involves much less overhead. Open file descriptors definitely do consume kernel resources; that's why processes are typically limited to 256 open files by default (not that the limit can't be expanded where appropriate).

Still, the pipe/poll solution for inter-thread communication does have advantages too: particularly if you need to wait for input from a combination of sources (network + other threads).

Comment: Why would it take 3 system calls? a blind `write()` call will block if the pipe's buffers are full. if each thread only needs to listen to its own pipe, you can drop the `poll()` as well, simply waiting for `read()` to succeed

Comment: OP specifically said that he's using poll() to wait for multiple pipes from one consumer thread.

Comment: I have to read and write to one file (/dev/ttySxx serial) *and* be able to respond to commands from another thread. Blocking is out of question. If I for example have a 10 megabyte write on the serial I can't wait until it is finished if the application tells me that it wants to abort the transfer. 

Therefore two non-blocking files that I poll for: One for the serial port and one to receive commands.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want poll to wait for other things then you pretty much have to use pipes/eventfd since you cannot mix POSIX synchronization primitives with anything else (even with sockets). And if you spawn a new thread to deal with network event and convert these  to POSIX mutexes and the like then you probably already thrown their performance advantage out of the window.

Answer (score 1):

**Measure and you'll know.**  Full processes with pipes are sufficiently lightweight for lots of applications.  Other applications require something lighter weight, like OS threads (pthreads being the popular choice for many Unix apps), or superlightweight, like a user-level threads package that never goes into kernel mode except to handle I/O.   While the only way to know for sure is to measure, pipes are probably good enough for up to a few tens of threads, whereas you probably want user-level threads once you get to a few tens of thousands of threads.  Exactly where the boundaries should be drawn using today's codes, I don't know.  If I wanted to know, I would measure :-)

Comment: I guess I'm confused. I think Linux's NPTL implementation is kernel-level. Does glibc provide a user-level implementation on top of that?